# WebMatrix: Using @FileUpload Helper

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, helper, webmatrix

I have the `System.Web.Helpers.dll` and .xml files in the Bin folder of my website solution, but `VS 2010` complains about "The name '`FileUpload' does not exists in the current context`" event though I use `@using System.Web.Helpers`;

```
@using System.Web.Helpers;
<td>@FileUpload.GetHtml(
       initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
       allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
       includeFormTag: false,
       uploadText: "Upload"
)</td>
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileUpload` is not in [`System.Web.Helpers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers%28v=vs.99%29.aspx). It is in `Microsoft.Web.Helpers`, which you can get from the [Package Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749465%28WS.10%29.aspx). Look for `ASP.NET Web Helpers Library`.

**Installation**

Right click on the project and choose `Add Library Package Reference`, or use the `Package Manager Console and type`

*Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers*

Answer (score 2):

Watch out... if your using mcv3 make sure you install microsoft-web-helper 1.15, if you dont specify version in package manager it will automatically install version 2.0 and mess everything up as only mvc4 is compatible with 2.0.

CORRECT COMMAND SHOULD BE:

```
Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers -Version 1.15
```

Answer (score 2):

just go to packages.config in your project and remove 
package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40"

clean your project

later install nuGet Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc

that's it